# Broadleaf Admin Panel Too Slow. Any Pointers to Optimize it?

Tags: spring, hibernate, amazon-ec2, broadleaf-commerce

I have hosted broadleaf admin panel on Amazon EC2 instance.
The admin panel takes a lot of time to load (maybe because everything is database driven). 
Every click costs me a good 30 seconds to load completely so that the page is in usable state.

Is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: Have you done any type of profiling?

Answer (score 0):

What are the specs of your EC2 instance? And what are the specs of the database tha you hook up to?

We recommend giving the JVM at least 1.5GB of RAM for each application that you have deployed. So if you have both the site and admin deployed to the same Tomcat instance, that's' 3GB total. You can change this in Tomcat's setenv.sh with CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1536m"

Comment: I have hosted "_admin_" and "_site_" on different tomcat instances (physically different servers). Both have same specs:-
*t2.micro instance,1 GB RAM,single core*
My "_site_" instance works fine but my "_admin_" instance is very slow (30 seconds per page load).
For database, there is one separate physical server. Both "admin" and "site" connect to the same instance. It is an Amazon _RDS instance(MySQL)_ with same configuration *t2.micro instance,1 GB RAM,single core*